# Hide close button in a scheduled toast notification in Windows 10

Tags: notifications, windows-runtime, windows-10, background-task

Toast notification have a "close button" in the upper right corner.
Is there any way to either *hide* this button or to *react* to the user clicking it?

The use case is this: I want to reschedule a notification for the next day whenever a user reacts to the notification, even when closing it. In other words: the user cannot dismiss the notification forever.

The notification is scheduled from a background task which might not be running anymore when the notification is dismissed.

Comment: In my opinion, this request can not be done. And a background task running or not is not directly related to a notification toast, you will need to find out other reason which makes your background task  stop running.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT: Ok, I see that I cannot intercept the closing of the notification. I will probably use a time-triggered background task to renew the scheduled notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it, or trigger an action when the 'x' icon clicked..

But, for your scenario, I'd suggest you to schedule the notification every day (or what ever your needs) and make it interactive notification (add a 'take action' button).. then if the user just dismissed it or closed it by whatever.. your Background Task is already running and your notifications are scheduled.. and the last option is to click on the take action, and then you can un schedule the notifications or stop the background task => your business logic :)